# Time and space complexity of x[::-1] when x in a string

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity

Consider the following code:

```
x = 'some string'
x = x[::-1]
```

Reversing a string is O(n). When we do x[::-1], I assume python is simply selecting the indexes of the string characters from last to first. He does that n times. (n = length of string).
Therefore is it correct to say that "x = x[::-1]" is:

- O(n) in time complexity
- O(n) is space complexity (has to reallocate memory for the newly reversed string

And without assignment ('x[::-1]') it is simply O(n) in time complexity and O(1) in space ?

Comment: you'll need to look at the implementation

Comment: It should be O(n) in both time and space complexity.  If the result is discarded, that probably won't change unless it's smart enough to optimize it away completely, in which case it would take no time or space at all (O(1) in both time and space complexity).

Comment: Thanks @TomKarzes that is what I am wondering, whether Python does this optimally in O(1) or not

Comment: Discarding the result doesn't reduce the amount of memory required to produce the result, any more than it reduces the time to produce the result.  Python generally can't optimize code away, because it can't be sure this won't change the meaning of your program (`x` might be a custom object that has some desirable side-effect when sliced, for example).

Comment: @slymore I'd be surprised if it optimized this away.  The cases where it does this are things like removing the code for `if False:`, which is one of the few optimizations it's known to do.

Comment: Yes @jasonharper it was indeed a confusion I was making (for memory), thanks for expliciting it. About your second remark: I'd think that x being a string there isn't any additional meaning it could hold, thus this kind of operation would be optimized for base types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has O(n) for both time and space complexity.  There are very few cases where Python optimizes away code.  It will optimize `if False:` code away, for example.  But for something like this it won't.

Consider these two functions:

```
def foo1(x):
    return x[::-1]

def foo2(x):
    x[::-1]
```

Now look at the "disassembler" output for these two functions:

```
>>> dis.dis(foo1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
              8 BUILD_SLICE              3
             10 BINARY_SUBSCR
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>> 
>>> dis.dis(foo2)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
              8 BUILD_SLICE              3
             10 BINARY_SUBSCR
             12 POP_TOP
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

As you can see, they both include `BUILD_SLICE` and `BINARY_SUBSCR`.  The only difference is that `foo1` then does `RETURN_VALUE`, while `foo2` does `POP_TOP` to discard the value, then `LOAD_CONST` to load `None` before doing `RETURN_VALUE`.

Comment: I've learned about the existence of the disassembler thanks to your post :)

Comment: @slymore Yeah, it's interesting to see what it does with certain things :)